# How to refer to a local file for a PowerPivot datasource?

Tags: 2010, excel, performancepoint, powerpivot

We have users trying to use `Performance Point` and need to point to a local `PowerPivot` file as a data source.  The instructions state:

```
 Type the connection string to the PowerPivot data source by using the following format: PROVIDER=MSOLAP;DATA SOURCE=http://contoso/Documents/PowerPivot_Sample.xlsx
```

Is the `Documents` a local Sharepoint directory?  Im assuming the 'contoso' is the servername, but Im unsure how to give sharepoint access to the files via a URL.

Answer (score 0):

In that case yes, Documents is a document library off the root site collection containing PowerPivot_Sample.xlsx.

In your environment, is the PowerPivot report stored in SharePoint already? If so, navigate to the document library, mouse over the name of the file and right click copy link location. Use that as the url in the datasource.

Comment: I will give this a try, I do believe they have uploaded the powerpivot report into Sharepoint.